# VB.NET I generated pictureboxes and LOOP it to my rows.Count, the problem is how can i call the PHOTOS?

Tags: vb.net, loops, for-loop

So basically i generated picture boxes through codes to increment it whenever i ADD data in my database.. my problem is how can i get the PHOTOS from my database to be in my picture boxes.

Here is my code:

```
connection.Open()
        cmd.Connection = connection
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID, Candidate_Name, Candidate_Fname,c_Photo from softeng.candidates"

        da.SelectCommand = cmd

        da.Fill(pdt)




                For j As Integer = 0 To pdt.Rows.Count - 1

                    Dim a As String = pdt.Rows(j).Item(0)
                    Dim b As String = pdt.Rows(j).Item(1)
                    Dim c As String = pdt.Rows(j).Item(2)





                    Dim pb As New PictureBox
                    Dim lb As New Label


                    lb.Name = "lbid" & j
                    lb.Text = "Candidate ID:" & a & vbCrLf & b + c & vbCrLf

                    lb.AutoSize = True
                    lb.Size = New Point(100, 100)



                    pb.Name = "pb" & j
                    pb.Text = a


                    pb.AutoSize = True
                    pb.Size = New Point(100, 100)
                    pb.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D



                    FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(pb)
                    FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(lb)

                Next


            connection.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

My codes for retrieving Pictures from my Database

```
 Dim data As Byte() = DirectCast(dr("Photo"), Byte())
                    Dim ms As New MemoryStream(data)
                    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
```

How can i put it to my code so i can retrieve photos when im looping my picture boxes?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you must make sure you are saving the images as binaries in database, then basically you read the binary information and convert it to an image object, showing in your control.

I'm pretty sure the link below has everything you need:

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-Binary-Image-from-Database-in-PictureBox-control-in-Windows-Application-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: Actually i did, my problem is the name..

like picturebox1.image.. which in this case i did increment the name like "pb" & j